# Wrapping a constructor in decorator in python

Tags: python, constructor, python-decorators

I want to have a handy decorator that checks if the value of attribute passed to the method is not None. I then want to use it as a general purpose decorator in class methods. For this, I wrote:

```
def check_empty(name):
  def wrap_outer(function):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
      if kwargs.get(name, None) is None:
        raise Exception('{item} cannot be empty'.format(item=name))
      return function(args, kwargs)
    return wrapped
  return wrap_outer
```

And, the class is defined as:

```
class Player(object):
  @check_empty('name')
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

def __str__(self):
  return self.name
```

However, this does not work. The template for the constructor and the decorator do not match. How can we create a function decorator for a constructor? Or is class based decorator a better option?

---

Thanks to @ajax1234, I figured out the problem. It was in the way I was passing down my `args` and `kwargs`. It should have been:

```
def check_empty(attr):
  def wrap_outer(function):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
      if (len(args) > 1 and args[1] is None) or (len(args)==1 and len(kwargs)==0):
        raise Exception('{item} cannot be empty'.format(item=attr))
      elif attr in kwargs and kwargs.get(attr, None) is None:
        raise Exception('{item} cannot be empty'.format(item=attr))
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapped
return wrap_outer
```

This takes care of checking on the parameter if it is passed as a keyword argument or just a positional argument.

**NOTE:** It does have a restriction that positional argument logic won't scale well while maintaining the generic nature. (We'd need to look into the positional argument's position using `inspect.getargspec` and then build up from there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def check_empty(attr):
   def check_method(function):
     def wrapped(cls, **kwargs):
       if kwargs.get(attr) is None:
         raise Exception('{item} cannot be empty'.format(item=attr))
       return function(cls, **kwargs)
     return wrapped
   return check_method

class Player(object):
  @check_empty('name')
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__ = kwargs
  def __str__(self):
     return self.name

p = Player(name=None)
```

Output:

```
Exception: Name cannot be empty
```

However, any parameter other than `None` works:

```
p = Player(name = 'Foo')
print(p.name)
```

Output:

```
'Foo'
```

Comment: Hi, what I am attempting is to make a general purpose decorator which can check any variable name. For example, if alongwith `name`, I had an `age` variable too, I'd like to use the same decorator twice.

Comment: Thank You! This works fine for the given scenario. Also, on wondering why your `cls` worked and `argc` didn't  I figured out my mistake too. I was passing `args` and `kwargs` in `return function(args, kwargs)` when I should have been passing `*args` and `**kwargs` as `return function(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see you being able to do what you want, while including positional and keyword arguments, is to provide the mapping of positions to names, like so:

```
class NoneException(Exception):
    pass


def check_none(**check):
    def wrapper(fn):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            for key, pos in check.items():
                try:
                    if kwargs[key] == None:
                        raise NoneException(f'{key} cannot be empty')
                except KeyError:
                    pass

                try:
                    if args[pos] == None:
                        raise NoneException(f'{key} cannot be empty')
                except IndexError:
                    pass

            return fn(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapped

    return wrapper


class A:
    @check_none(name=1)
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @check_none(phrase=1)
    def test(self, phrase):
        print(f'My name is {self.name}. {phrase}!')


a = A('A')

a.test('Hello world!')

try:
    a.test(None)
except NoneException:
    print('successfully failed')
else:
    print('something went wrong')
```

This should cover the cases of where you provide an argument positionally and explicitly named, *however* note that it is a brittle solution considering that the mapping of positional argument indexes must be maintained.

If there were some way to reflectively divine the mapping `self=0, name=1, et cetera` from Python's internals, I would suggest to use that instead.

---

Alternatively, a simpler solution is a function call at the top of each function you'd want to check.

```
class NoneException(Exception):
    pass

def check_none(*args, **kwargs):
    for key, value in (*enumerate(args), *kwargs.items()):
        if value == None:
            raise NoneException(f'key {key} == None')

class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        check_none(name)

        self.name = name
```

Comment: You are right about the positional brittleness of the decorator scheme. That can be taken care of. I did that part later and realised that it would still be poor at scale when chaining decorators. So yes, using a utility function would be much better at almost the same writing cost. :-)